# Why does convert(datetime,getdate(),101) yields different results while executed in stored procedure and a simple select command?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Don't know why but while running the command

```
select CONVERT(datetime, getdate(),101)
```

gets `'2016-10-27 15:53:12.743'`, which is the desired result.

However when the same command is run in a Stored Procedure like

```
if @CodeFilter2 is not null
select @CodeFilter2=CONVERT(datetime,GETDATE(),101)
```

yields `'Oct 27 2016  3:55PM'`.

Please help me understand as to why is this happening.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is far from ANSI SQL.)

Comment: How you are passing this parameter  `@CodeFilter2`

Comment: What you **see** is **not the real value** but a **string representation** of your datetime value, The format used is bound to the context, settings, system's culture and server's language. That is the reason why one should always try to avoid any culture specific datetime format or any storage of datetime on string base...

Comment: i found why is it happening,the datatype of the parameter "@CodeFilter2" is defined as nvarchar ,which is supposed to be datetime.that solved the issue.thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're converting a `datetime` to a `datetime`? Are you expecting that the format used in `convert` sticks around? It's just ignored, since it has no meaning for the conversion you're doing. If you want to convert a datetime to a varchar, you need to use something like `convert(varchar(max), getDate(), 101)`, which will give you the correct output `10/27/2016` - I have no idea why you'd expect either of your samples to be correct; they simply happen to work that way because the default conversion (based on locale and other context, which is very variable) happens to be your desired result (in the first case).

If you need to rely on specific formatting *you must use explicit formatting*. Or let the application handle it instead of the DB server. The proper format for the ODBC cannonical form (which seems to be the one you desire) is 121. Make sure you're converting to `varchar` or `nvarchar`, not `datetime`.

Comment: i found why is it happening,the datatype of the parameter "@CodeFilter2" is defined as nvarchar ,which is supposed to be datetime.that solved the issue.thank you